# How to clean a string using python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string which have to clean

```
#import re

addr="abcd&^fhj"
problemchars = re.compile(r'[=\+/&<>;\'"\?%#$@\,\. \t\r\n]')
re.search(problemchars,addr)
```

Comment: you want to remove non-alphanum chars?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes

Comment: what exactly you wanna achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case use `re.sub` searching `\W` (non-alphanum) and replacing by nothing.

```
import re

addr="abcd&^fhj"
print(re.sub("\W","",addr))
```

(`"\W+"` works too, but not sure it would be more performant)

Answer (score 1):

you could use the filter function as well if you don't want to go with regex

```
line = "abcd&^fhj"
line = filter(str.isalpha, line)
print line # Change for python3
```

Output :

```
abcdfhj
```

Edit: For python 3 you could change the print statement like this since the `filter` function returns an iterable.

```
print(''.join(list(line)))
```

Comment: that's a nice touch. Please provide Python 3.x compatible code: I mean `line = "".join(filter(str.isalpha, line))` because `filter` won't return a string but an iterable.